# Do initializers (initializerConfiguration) work on k8s 1.10?

Tags: kubernetes

I tried (unsuccessfully) to set up an initializer admission controller on k8s 1.10, running in minikube. kubectl does not show 'initializerconfiguration' as a valid object type and attempting 'kubectl create -f init.yaml' with a file containing an initializerConfiguration object (similar to the exmaple found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#configure-initializers-on-the-fly) returns this:

no matches for kind "InitializerConfiguration" in version "admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

(I tried with /v1beta1 as well, because kubectl api-versions doesn't show admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1 but does have .../v1beta1; no luck with that, either).

"Initializers" is enabled in the --admission-control option for kube-apiserver and all possible APIs are also turned on by default in minikube - so it should have worked, according to the k8s documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) mentioned in question:

> ### Enable initializers alpha feature
>
> Initializers is an alpha feature, so it is disabled by default. To
>   turn it on, you need to:
>
> - Include “Initializers” in the `--enable-admission-plugins` flag when starting `kube-apiserver`. If you have multiple `kube-apiserver`
>     replicas, all should have the same flag setting.
> - Enable the dynamic admission controller registration API by adding `admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1` to the `--runtime-config` flag
>     passed to `kube-apiserver`, e.g.
>     `--runtime-config=admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1`. Again, all
>     replicas should have the same flag setting.

NOTE: For those looking to use this on `minikube`, use this to pass `runtime-config` to the apiserver:

`minikube start --vm-driver=none --extra-config=apiserver.runtime-config=admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true`

Comment: Worked - AFTER I figured out the equivalent of --runtime-config in minikube. The Initializers plugin is actually enabled already in 1.10, as noted in my post, --enable-admission-plugins was not needed. I **finally** found how to pass the 'runtime-config' option to minikube, there was only one useful reference to this:
minikube start --vm-driver=none 
--extra-config=apiserver.runtime-config=admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true